# error when using exception handling to prevent system from crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to use exception handling to prevent my system from crashing, I used the below codes where this csv file does not actually exist. But the system is crashing even though. Can someone help me to correct my codes please....help me please

These are my source codes:

```
while True:
    try:
        import pandas as pd  # data processing, csv file I/O(e.g pd.read_csv)

        df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv')
        print(df)
    except Exception as err:
            print("Uh oh, please send me this message: '" + err + "'")
```

The errors I am having

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/EmotionAnalysis/abcd.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/assd.csv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/EmotionAnalysis/abcd.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("Uh oh, please send me this message: '" + err + "'")
TypeError: must be str, not FileNotFoundError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate an Exception to a string, you can do this instead:

```
print("Uh oh, please send me this message: '{}'".format(err))
```

Comment: Dear sir, it is working, but it is giving me the output for so many lines. can I get this for only one line?